Error running Visual Studio’s instrumented performance profiler
We have a very complex application containing a mixture of native and managed code. In total, we have C, C++, C++ CLI, Fortran, and C#, all in one application.
I'd really like to use the instrumentation profiler because our application is pretty much entirely IO/network bound, not CPU bound, so the sampling CPU profiler isn't very useful in our case.
I put together a bunch of test projects to roughly mimic our application structure: A C++ static lib, a C++ DLL, and a C# (.NET Framework) application, each in its own solution, and I was able to run the instrumentation profiler by linking the DLL with the /PROFILE option. To run the profiler, I selected "Executable" and navigated to the prebuilt target, and then after clicking the start button I added the DLL to be instrumented. This all worked perfectly and the resulting flame graph made sense.
However, the same approach with our real project results in a crash. I follow much the same procedure described above, but I only select 1 of our DLLs to be instrumented. On the release build, the application just quits shortly after I start recording. On the debug build, it says after a few seconds "Microsoft Visual Studio canceled starting your diagnostics session", and in the output window it says "Unexpected exception. Check logs for details". The log file at %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\\ActivityLog.xml doesn't contain any clues. If I don't select any DLL to be instrumented, the profiler doesn't gather any information at all.
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.10.4

I don't see why a temporal sampling CPU profiler (like Intel's Vtune) won't work for you (to find the hotspots). I have always found MS instrumentation far too invasive and it disturbs the code being profiled to such an extent that the results are meaningless. As ever YMMV if your code it so very different and network/IO dependent. Mine is heavily CPU/cache/memory bandwidth limited so quite a different scenario.

Haven’t tried VTune yet, but the problem with sampling profilers is that if your thread is asleep because it’s blocked on IO or network, when the profiler asks the CPU “what code are you running?” as it does 1000 times per second, it won’t see the sleeping thread because it’s not currently executing, so that sample isn’t counted. The result is that the time spent on IO and network isn’t represented in the profile, and for us that’s most of the actual wall clock time. I don’t care about what’s eating the most clock cycles as we’re so IO/network bound we barely touch the CPU.

I thought it might be something like that. You could maybe add your own instrumentation and then have a sacrificial thread that consists of CPU time wasting while loops that depend on which part of the code is blocking on IO waits. Beware that the MS profiling instrumentation can change code behaviour in unpredictable ways - use with caution.
